# Is there a way to monitor the time spend on a loop and act on the time in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, iteration

I'm looping over something for web **scraping** and it sometimes gets stuck.

I wonder if there is a way to monitor the loop simultaneously when it's executing something so that if a loop takes more than a specified time (let's say 30s), it raises an error to interrupt it?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html See the example at the bottom.